# How Do I Fix a mysql "system error: 111" in a hosting service?

Tags: mysql

Got this error

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

I am currently hosting a site under a subdomain

here is a page accessing the database :

http://payment.ygamtester.co.cc/search/index.html

I have seen a lot of posts about this all pointing to one solution

use ssh to alter a file in the mysql server

obviously you can't do that with a remotely hosted site under a hosting company

Comment: Then I suggest you contact your hosting provider, or move to another one if they don't help you.

Answer (score 2):

You call THEIR SUPPORT. Is it so hard not to ask on a random forum without even telling which host it is but to first contacct the people maintaining the server? Just open a ticket with their support.

Answer (score 0):

you much change  database connection from 127.0.0.1 to localhost